# Apache TIKA vs PdfBox (HTML)

Tags: text, pdfbox, apache-tika, text-extraction

I'm trying to convert pdf files into HTML.

When using the PDFBox jar the following:

```
java -jar pdfbox-app-2.0.7.jar ExtractText -html 1.pdf
```

I'm getting a valid HTML file as expected.

But when using

```
tika --html 1.pdf
```

I'm getting a file missing a lot of tags, such as `<b>`, `<i>` etc
I saw that TIKA is using PDFBox as the pdf extractor, so I guess there must be a way to get the same result, but I can't seem to find the right way to do that.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If the Apache PDFBox converter works well for you, why not keep using it?

Comment: because our process contains many file formats, and we want to use tika instead of implementing different approaches....